# yard, How to include image to documentation?

Tags: ruby, yard

I want to include image in yard-genereted documentation, but can't find anywhere how to do this... Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add `<img />` tag to your documentation:

```
 # Blah-blah 
 # 
 # <img src=img/1.png />
 # @param [String] blah
 # @return [String] blah
 def foo(bar) 

 end
```

Comment: This does work for me(rails 3.1.0, Yard 0.7.2). The text is html escaped: `&lt;img src='img/1.png' /&gt;`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`rdoc-image:`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/RDoc/Markup.html#class-RDoc::Markup-label-Links) links:

```
# Gets foo.
#
# rdoc-image:img/1.png
def foo(bar)
  "foo"
end
```

is rendered by YARD into

```html
<p>Gets foo.</p>
<p><img src="img/1.png"></p>
```

The `rdoc-images:` also works in standalone `*.rdoc` files.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your markup format you may have to use another mechanism. For instance, if you use Markdown, the syntax is `![Alt text](/path/to/img.jpg)`. In RDoc, an img tag should work, but you can check if they have added a special markup syntax for this. Note that RDoc probably (not sure) doesn't like XHTML, you should use  with no ending /.